# Reference a table through a string representation of the name

Tags: progress-4gl

I'm trying to write a modular procedure, where I pass in a string representation of a table name, and query/update that table.

What I tried was something to this affect:

```
PROCEDURE foo:
    DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER chTableName AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    FIND FIRST VALUE(chTableName) NO-LOCK
    WHERE blahblahblah NO-ERROR.

    IF AVAIL VALUE(chTableName) THEN
    ASSIGN
         VALUE(chTableName).value = foo.
END PROCEDURE.
```

This obviously does not work, but hopefully this will get the point across of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Any help or info in this matter would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully you are running version 9 or better where dynamic queries are available.

```
procedure x:

  define input parameter tbl as character no-undo.
  define input parameter fld as character no-undo.
  define input parameter xyz as character no-undo.

  define variable qh as handle no-undo.
  define variable bh as handle no-undo.
  define variable fh as handle no-undo.

  create buffer bh for table tbl.
  create query qh.
  qh:set-buffers( bh ).
  qh:query-prepare( "for each " + tbl ).
  qh:query-open.

  do transaction:
    qh:get-first( exclusive-lock ).
    fh = bh:buffer-field( fld ).
    display fh:buffer-value.
    fh:buffer-value = xyz.
  end.

  delete object bh.
  delete object qh.

  return.

end.

run x ( "customer", "name", "fred" ).

find first customer no-lock.
display name.
```

Answer (score 2):

This can get you started:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt NO-UNDO
    FIELD a AS INTEGER.

PROCEDURE foo:
    DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER pcTable AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER pcWhere AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER pcField AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER piValue AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.

    DEFINE VARIABLE hBuffer AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE hQuery  AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.

    CREATE BUFFER hBuffer FOR TABLE pcTable.
    CREATE QUERY hQuery.   

    hQuery:SET-BUFFERS(hBuffer).

    hQuery:QUERY-PREPARE("FOR EACH " + pcTable + " WHERE " + pcWhere).

    hQuery:QUERY-OPEN().
    hQuery:GET-FIRST().

    IF hBuffer:AVAILABLE THEN DO:
        ASSIGN 
            hBuffer:BUFFER-FIELD(pcField):BUFFER-VALUE = piValue NO-ERROR.
        IF ERROR-STATUS:ERROR THEN DO:
            MESSAGE "Failed" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR.
        END.
    END.

    DELETE OBJECT hBuffer.
    DELETE OBJECT hQuery.


END PROCEDURE.

CREATE tt.
ASSIGN tt.a = 1.


RUN foo( INPUT "tt"
       , INPUT "tt.a = 1"
       , INPUT "a"
       , INPUT 2).

DISPLAY tt.
```

Comment: If it is a real table rather than a temp-table you need to wrap a DO TRANSACTION around the assignment logic.